# What programming languages are 'general purpose' and 'domain specific'?

Tags: javascript, ruby, dsl

I've read a few posts on SO about different DSL's and GP languages but I'm still a bit confused as to how you define a programming language to be one or the other.

My understanding so far (and hopefully you can clarify) is as follows:

Languages such as PHP, HTML, CSS are domain specific because they were designed for a singular purpose (e.g. they were designed for building websites - or in CSS' case was for styling websites). Whereas a language such as Ruby or Python is a general purpose language because it can be used for multiple purposes (e.g. Ruby can be used to build websites, as a command line tool, building Mac applications etc).

Would that be correct? And if so where does a language like JavaScript fit in which I believe was designed to be domain specific (e.g. it was designed to be used for adding interactivity to websites) but JavaScript can be run on the server or command line, it can be used to interact with software like Photoshop and even doing Windows Shell Scripting so could that be considered a general purpose language because it's used for multiple purposes OR is it still domain specific because it's origins were that it was designed for web?

Any clarification appreciated.

Comment: This is probably too subjective to make a good Stack Overflow question; there are no official definitions of these terms.  And as you point out, languages that were originally designed to solve a particular problem can become general over time.

Comment: OK, thanks any way. I can see my question has been migrated to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143638/what-programming-languages-are-general-purpose-and-domain-specific - what's that about? :-)